# Suggestions for improvement on Project Euler #7

Tags: java, project-euler, primes

Here is a solution for [Project Euler Problem #7](http://projecteuler.net/problem=7).

> By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can
>   see that the 6th prime is 13. What is the 10,001st prime number?

I've used the pseudo code from the [Wikipedia page for the Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Implementation).

> **Input:** an integer n > 1
>
> Let A be an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n, initially all set to true.
>
> ```
> for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., not exceeding √n:
>      if A[i] is true:
>          for j = i^2, i^2+i, i^2+2i, ..., not exceeding n :
>              A[j] := false
> ```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FindPrimesHashMap {
    public static void getPrime(int x) {
        int n = (x * ((int)Math.sqrt(x) / 10)) + x;
        int nSqrt = (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        Map<Integer, Boolean> primeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Boolean>> primes = primeMap.entrySet();
        ArrayList<Integer> primeArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int a = 2; a < n; a++) {
            primeMap.put(a, true);
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= nSqrt; i++) {
            if (primeMap.get(i)) {
                while (true) {
                    j = (i * i) + (k * i);
                    k++;

                    if (j > n) {
                        break;
                    }
                    primeMap.put(j, false);
                }
                j = 0;
                k = 0;
             }
        } 

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Boolean> entry : primes) {
            if (entry.getValue()) {
                primeArray.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(primeArray);
        System.out.println(primeArray.get(x - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

// Started this review before XMas dinner. now there are many other answers. .... will post anyway....

In some ways you follow the pseudo-code, and in others you deviate. In my opinion, you follow the worst aspects of the pseudo-code, and deviate from the best.

Things that you copy, but I would change are:

- Use more meaningful variable names.... `A`, `i`, `j`, and `n` are not great names, yet you have variables `a`, `i`, `j`, `k`, and `x`. Further, your `a` and the pseudo-`A` are different things.

Things you change, but I would copy:

- use an actual array-of-boolean for your sieve, instead of a `Map<Integer,Boolean>`

Further, there are a number of other issues I have concerns with:

- you create `primes` as a set of the Entries in the `primesMap` immediately after creating `primesMap`:

  ```
  Map<Integer, Boolean> primeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
  Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Boolean>> primes = primeMap.entrySet();
  ```

  For a while this had me confused.... I am flabbergasted, actually, that this works. That the `primes` set is correctly populated after populating the backing Map. Now, don't get me wrong, this **does** appear to actually work, but I have **never** seen this done this way, and you have taught **me** something! I have confirmed in the JavaDoc that the `entrySet()` is 'live', and changes as you change the backing Map. Unfortunately, I cannot recommend this practice - simply due to it's unconventionality.
- The line of code `int n = (x * ((int)Math.sqrt(x) / 10)) + x;` has me confused as well. What is this formula? Why does it work? How can you be sure that the `x'th` Prime is less than this value `n`? In fact, it cannot be right, the 5th prime is 11, but, in your case, `n` would be 5. You should read up on [this approximation of the *n* <sup>th</sup> prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number).
- It is a `C` type construct to declare your variables at the start of a method. Don't do this. In Java you should declare your variables as close to their usage as you can. It is a 'best practice' (although [there is some debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411463/in-java-should-variables-be-declared-at-the-top-of-a-function-or-as-theyre-ne)).
- In your loops you do not use convenient conditional `whiles`. The `while (true) ... break; ....` is particularly concerning. You should make the conditions more explicit

So, putting everything together, I would keep things as primitives. I would also make the limit of the sieve 'dynamic', and expand it as needed... perhaps 'seeding' it with some constants.

### EDIT:

... after some festive cheer, I re-visited this problem, and figured I would put together a class that incrementally calculates the primes. Call it a 'project'. This is a Sieve class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class caches prime numbers, and is able to provide you with the prime
 * numbers you want (up to close to Integer.MAX_VALUE)
 * 
 * @author rolfl
 * 
 */
public class EratosthenesSieve {
    // Since we play by inverting the logic of a boolean array,
    // I have constants that make the logic easier to see.
    private static final boolean PRIME = false;
    private static final boolean NOTPRIME = true;

    // Initialize to the first 5 primes.
    // Note, by seeding at least one odd prime, we never have to consider even
    // values in the sieve.
    private int[] primes = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 }; // seed initial primes.

    /**
     * Get the n<sup>th</sup> prime
     * 
     * @param nth
     *            The prime to get.
     * @return the n'th prime.
     */
    public int getNthPrime(final int nth) {
        if (nth < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Finding the " + nth
                    + " prime number is not possible");
        }

        while (nth >= primes.length) {
            // have not yet cached this prime.

            // NOTE: Integer.MAX_VALUE happens to be prime.
            // Maybe there is something we can do with that.

            // The estimated n'th prime: from Wikipedia:
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number
            final int lastprime = primes[primes.length - 1];
            // calculate forward to 25% of where we are, or 10% + 30 more than
            // the wiki guess.
            final long longapproxsize = Math.max((long) lastprime
                    + ((long) lastprime >> 2),
                    30 + (long) (nth * Math.log(nth) * 1.1));
            if (longapproxsize > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The " + nth
                        + " prime number is probably too large to calculate.");
            }
            // calculate at most 1Million primes in a loop (sieve size 1M)
            // (reduces maximum memory footprint);
            final int approxsize = Math.min((int) longapproxsize, lastprime + 1000000);
            // only need to create a sieve for what we have not yet calculated.
            // odd number after last prime.
            final int startfrom = lastprime + 2;

            final boolean[] sieve = new boolean[approxsize - startfrom];
            for (final int prime : primes) {
                // mark multiples of previously-calculated primes.
                if (prime == 2) {
                    // can ignore 2...
                    continue;
                }
                // calculating an odd-valued start position allows us to
                // optimize
                // by doing double-prime steps.
                int first = (prime - (startfrom % prime)) % prime;
                if (((first + startfrom) & 1) == 0) {
                    first += prime;
                }
                for (int j = first; j < sieve.length; j += prime + prime) {
                    sieve[j] = NOTPRIME;
                }
            }

            // OK, the sieve has been extended. But only the primes from the
            // previous round have been filtered...
            // our last prime was recorded in primes array.
            // we need to complete the prime sequence, then extract the new
            // primes.
            int pcnt = primes.length;
            int[] tmprime = Arrays.copyOf(primes, approxsize >> 1);
            int root = (int) (Math.sqrt(approxsize) + 1);
            int maxj = (int)(Math.sqrt(root) + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < sieve.length; i += 2) {
                if (sieve[i] == PRIME) {
                    // this is a newly discovered prime.
                    // record it
                    int prime = i + startfrom;
                    tmprime[pcnt++] = prime;
                    // clear any future multiples of this prime.
                    // optimize by starting from square, and ignoring even
                    // multiples.
                    // need j > 0 to avoid overflow issues.
                    if (prime > maxj) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    for (int j = prime * prime; j > 0 && j < root; j += prime + prime) {
                        if (j - startfrom < 0 || j - startfrom >= sieve.length) {
                            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("Cannot access index %d in array with length %d", j - startfrom, sieve.length));
                        }
                        sieve[j - startfrom] = NOTPRIME;
                    }
                }
            }
            // OK, we have our new primes recorded.
            primes = Arrays.copyOf(tmprime, pcnt);

        }
        return primes[nth - 1];

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EratosthenesSieve sieve = new EratosthenesSieve();

        // From wikipedia: all primes < 1000
        int[] data = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47,
                53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109,
                113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179,
                181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241,
                251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313,
                317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389,
                397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461,
                463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547,
                557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617,
                619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691,
                701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773,
                787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859,
                863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947,
                953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997 };

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            int act = sieve.getNthPrime(i + 1);
            if (act != data[i]) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not calculate "
                        + (i + 1) + " prime. Expect " + data[i] + " but got "
                        + act);
            }
            System.out.println("Prime " + (i + 1) + " is " + act);
        }

        for (int i = 1000000; i > 0; i += 1000000) {
            int act = sieve.getNthPrime(i);
            System.out.println("Prime " + i + " is " + act);
        }

    }

}
```

<strike>here is some code I think better represents what should be done.... with some optimizations for Java:</strike>

```
public static final int findNthPrime(final int nth) {
    if (nth < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Finding the " + nth + " prime number is not possible");
    }
    // we make a special case of prime number 2, so that we only need to deal with half the numbers (odd numbers only) 
    if (nth == 1) {
        return 2;
    }

    // The estimated n'th prime: from Wikipedia:
    //    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number
    // add 25% because the approximation always under-estimates.
    final int approxsize = (int)(nth * Math.log(nth) * 1.25);
    // because boolean arrays are initialized to false, we will reverse our logic to
    // avoid re-filling the arrays, hence isnotprime instead of isprime.
    boolean[] isnotprime = new boolean[approxsize];
    int startfrom = 3;
    while (true) {
        // we may need to expand the sieve in unusual conditions.
        final int root = (int)Math.sqrt(isnotprime.length) + 1;
        for (int i = startfrom; i < root; i+=2) {
            for (int j = i * i; j < isnotprime.length; j += i) {
                isnotprime[j] = true;
            }
        }
        // even though we have only iterated to `root`, we have actually calculated all the primes to isnotprime.length.
        // let's check ahead of `root` to see if our n'th prime has been calculated.
        int tmpprimecount = 1;
        for (int i = 3; i < isnotprime.length; i+=2) {
            if (!isnotprime[i]) {
                if (++tmpprimecount == nth) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("The Wiki approximation is supposed to be good enough to cover this.");

        // we were not able to find the nth prime in the estimated space.
        // expand the estimated space
        // tmp.length will be odd, always.
//            boolean[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(isnotprime, 1 + isnotprime.length * 2);
//            for (int i = 3; i < root; i += 2) {
//                if (!tmp[i]) {
//                    startfrom = i;
//                    for (int j = isnotprime.length; j < tmp.length; j+= i) {
//                        tmp[j] = true;
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//            isnotprime = tmp;
    }
```

Comment: This is actually my first time using a map, and also my first week of using java, hopefully this will explain some of the poorly written parts of the code! I will thoroughly read into all of your suggestions. Thank you very much for taking the time to help.

Comment: Updated answer to have a more comprehensive solution (make the accept-rep more worth it ...)

Comment: @rolf int first = (prime - (startfrom % prime)) % prime;
                if (((first + startfrom) & 1) == 0) {
                    first += prime;
                }
                for (int j = first; j < sieve.length; j += prime + prime) {
                    sieve[j] = NOTPRIME;
                } This piece of code is great but whats the official name of this theoram ? Is there some url you can paste to let me know the "official proof" of how it assures correctness ? I am especially confused about `int first = (prime - (startfrom % prime)) % prime` Thanks

Comment: @JavaDeveloper join us in the [2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor), can go through it with you there.

Answer (score 6):

You have a proliferation of cryptically named variables, making your code hard to follow.

Variables `j` and `k` are only ever used inside the `while (true)` loop, so they should be declared in a tighter scope.  There is no need to reset `j` after the loop.  Also, it would be easier to understand your code if you reset `k = 0` before the loop rather than afterwards.  The `while (true)` loop could be simplified to:

```
for (int k = 0; ; k++) {
    int j = (i * i) + (k * i);
    if (j > n) {
        break;
    }
    primeMap.put(j, false);
}
```

Then, why not eliminate `k` altogether?

```
for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i) {
    primeMap.put(j, false);
}
```

---

I don't see why you set `n = x ⌈√x / 10⌉`.  It seems that you chose it as an estimate for the upper bound of your answer, though I don't understand the justification.  The answer should be somewhere around [*p*<sub>*x*</sub> ≈ *x*  ln(*x*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number).

In the end, it's not really important *how* you arrived at `n`, as long as it is large enough.  An explanatory comment would have been appreciated, though.

---

Using a `HashMap` to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes is not a great idea, because:

1. You want to iterate through the results consecutively
2. All of the keys were initially consecutive
3. Internally, it will be hashing each key to another number

It would be a lot simpler if you simply used an array of `boolean`s.

Comment: Thank you very much. In regards to the calculation of "n" you are correct. I wanted to come up with a relationship that would always create a map large enough to find the xth prime. Also I see your point regarding my naming, will fix.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe consider a simple array of `Boolean`s instead of `primeMap`, or an array of integers from indices, to get rid of that copy to another array:

1. initialization

   ```
   {0,0,2,3,4,5,6}
   ```
2. remove non-primes through `for` and `while` loop

   ```
   {0,0,2,3,0,5,0}
   ```
3. sort

   ```
   {0,0,0,0,2,3,5}
   ```
4. find 1<sup>st</sup> non-zero integers index for correction or for sublist

Answer (score 1):

Well since you didn't mention what kind of improvement you are looking for, I will share some short(LOC) and precise way to find X<sup>th</sup> prime number.

```
public static BigInteger getXthPrime(final int x) {
    BigInteger prime = new BigInteger("2"); // first prime number
    int noOfPrimes = 1; // since we already considered a prime
    while(noOfPrimes != x) {
        prime = prime.nextProbablePrime();
        noOfPrimes++;
    }
    return prime;
}
```

**NOTE** : This is a *very slow* method and will take more time as `x` grow larger.

Comment: That should probably be written as a for-loop.